# How to call the scheduler.Start() again after shutdown()? (quartz.net 3.0.2 and C#)

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am creating an application that uses quartz.net scheduler (3.0.2 version). I need to make the scheduler works for say many months or years. I dont see other tutorials related to this after googling alot.

So far I have been following the samples used in the site - https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html.

and

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html

For this one....
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

From this code, I can change it to await Task.Delay(-1) to make it work continuously without shut down if i want to have the scheduler works for many months or years.

Would this be ideal not having to touch the "await scheduler.Shutdown();" part?

Plans is to put it in IIS later.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Logging;

namespace QuartzSampleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new ConsoleLogProvider());

            RunProgramRunExample().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the application");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task RunProgramRunExample()
        {
            try
            {
                // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
                NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
                };
                StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
                IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

                // and start it off
                await scheduler.Start();

                // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();

                // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

                // some sleep to show what's happening
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

                // and last shut down the scheduler when you are ready to close your program
                await scheduler.Shutdown();
            }
            catch (SchedulerException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se);
            }
        }

        ..........
}
```

I am not sure of any other options. Other options will be calling Start() again after shutdown() part. But how to do that?

Comment: "_Would this be ideal_" No. The Task will wait infinitely and you lose the control over your app. Just let your `RunProgramRunExample()` return the `Scheduler` and call `.Shutdown()` after `Console.ReadKey();` in your Main method.

Comment: Then how do we loop it. for the next schedule. Main purpose is to run the job as per schedule. After shutdown(), the job wont run the next schedule. Say the run the task everyday at 9pm.

changing the TriggerBuilder to run every day at 9pm.

then calling shutdown after that. So for the next day. How do we run that as it is already shutdowned.